# Javascript string formatting - replace in string saved in a variable

Tags: javascript, string.format

Task is simple write numbers from 1 to 99 and replace all numbers where: `num (mod 3) =0` with each `num (mod 5) =0 -> mat`, `num ( mod 3=0 && mod 5=0 )` with each mat, all others remains the same. That is easy but the formatting is horrible so I want to do this: insert a space between every number and place every "special" word (dividable by 3,5 or both) on a separate line. I know I have to use `string.prototype.format` but how exactly? here is my current code:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to join two strings into one new string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>


function myFunction() {
     var text = []; 
      var res = " ";   

     for (i=1; i<100; i++){
   if (i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0){
        text[i]= "SachMat ";
                }
       else if (i%3 == 0){
        text[i]= 'sach ';
                }
        else if (i%5 == 0){
        text[i]= 'mat ';
                }

        else {
        text[i]= i;                
                }       
      var res = res.concat(text[i]);
       }


 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function myFunction() {
    var text = []; 
    var res = " ";   

    for (i=1; i<100; i++){
        if (i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0){
            text[i]= "<br/>SachMat<br/>";
        } else if (i%3 == 0) {
            text[i]= 'sach ';
        } else if (i%5 == 0){
            text[i]= 'mat ';
        } else {
            text[i]= i;                
        }       
        res = res.concat(' ' + text[i]);
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```